# Elasticsearch order by field in child document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which look like this:

```
{
    "parent" : {
        "properties" : {
            "id": {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
            "name" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and child documents:

```
{
    "child": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "parent"
        },
        "_routing": {
            "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "child_id": {
                "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "child_name" : {
                 "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "child_time": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I sort parent documents by child_name of child with the latest child_time?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the details, because I dont understand them yet, but I found this workaround:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-has-child-query.html#_sorting

The according feature-request, which would provide an explicit way to sort by value on child-documents, was closed:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2917

Answer (score 0):

**this might help someone**

child documents sorted by parent doc of associated child

```
const { body } = await elasticWrapper.client.search({
        index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
        pretty: true,
        filter_path: 'hits.hits._source*',
        _source: ['user.id', 'user.name', 'user.thumbnail'],
        body: {
          from: f ? f : 0,
          size: s ? s : 10,
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: [
                {
                  match: {
                    recordStatus: RecordStatus.Active,
                  },
                },
                {
                  match: {
                    relation_type: ElasticRelationType.Child,
                  },
                },
                {
                  bool: {
                    should: tagsA
                      ? tagsA.map((name: string) => {
                          return {
                            nested: {
                              path: 'tags',
                              query: {
                                match: {
                                  'tags.name': name,
                                },
                              },
                            },
                          };
                        })
                      : [],
                  },
                },
                {
                  has_child: {
                    parent_type: ElasticRelationType.Parent,
                    score: true,
                    query: {
                      function_score: {
                        script_score: {
                          script: {
                            lang: 'expression',
                            source: "_score * doc['rating']",
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      });
```